# No feedback and not included in any project meetings

Tags: work-environment, software-development, meetings, quality

I am a QA analyst. I have been testing for a little over 2 years now and I recently (~ 4 months ago) started a job at a small company with less than 20 employees. I work alongside another senior QA analyst who was the only analyst for 10 years.

Early on I have begun to notice I receive little to no feedback. I had one sit down status meeting with my boss who couldn't give me specific criticisms or advice pertaining to my position. I work closely with the director who is generally open and communicates okay regarding my work. The senior QA analyst is somewhat distant and perhaps even "hands off" with me. I have overheard them say that I was a very self reliant and independent which is a good thing.

What worries me is that I am not included in any high level development meetings. As a QA in my old position, I was very involved in almost all aspects of development, where I was asked to provide my opinion and suggestion often. In my new position, I am not asked to join any project status meetings and usually only get introduced to a project after devs are onto another. I don't necessarily think that this is specific to me as I do not see my QA counterpart invited to these meetings as well.

It can be quite isolating when I feel so out of the loop on current and new projects. It feels almost as if quality is an afterthought at my job and it makes me feel very undervalued to the point where I hold back feedback regarding features because I feel as if it doesn't matter.

I am very excited and eager to become a better analyst and want to succeed in making my company's projects better, however I feel almost invisible some days. I also know that devs want the feedback as well.

I guess my question is **what can I do as a new QA to place more emphasis on quality and show my boss that QA should and needs to be included in important design and development meetings?**

When I first on-boarded I openly suggested that we be involved very early on in the process, however my boss's opinion was that he didn't see the need. How can he ever see the need if he doesn't know the difference? And if they refuse to let us in earlier or recognize our importance is it worth sticking around?

Comment: How recently did you joined this new company? Perhaps it's too early yet for them to value your opinion as strongly as on your last company

Comment: @darkcygnus Thanks for the response. About 4 months ago. I do understand that I am a newbie in their eyes but I feel that I've picked up on their software pretty quickly. I dont expect them to immediately respond to every suggestion or issue I find but I do expect to be included in regular status meetings. At my old company I was pretty much let into all that on day one and I was new at testing. The senior QA is also not included very much and when I brought this up he seemed like he just deals with it.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess my question is what can I do as a new QA to place more emphasis on quality and show my boss that QA should and needs to be included in important design and development meetings?

As a recent hire, **few things, besides doing good work and letting the results speak for themselves.**

You say that it seems your senior QA is also not included in meetings. If this is true, then it would mean that for the last 10 years your boss hasn't considered including any QA staff on meetings a priority.

If this has been the case for the past 10 years chances are slim for your boss to change his mind now and start including you on meetings.

> When I first on-boarded I openly suggested that we be involved very early on in the process, however my boss's opinion was that he didn't see the need.

This is another clue that what I said is true. Your boss clearly stated that he didn't consider this a priority, or something that should be done.

With all this in mind, I'd say that *for this company* QA is different than what you previous company considered, suggesting that the current one does care for Quality but not enough to include it on meetings and other moments.

> How can he ever see the need if he doesn't know the difference? And if they refuse to let us in earlier or recognize our importance is it worth sticking around?

For the first question we would be guessing, but perhaps something on the last 10 years or before led your boss to make that choice.

If not being included on meetings is a no-go *for you* then by all means consider what is best for your interest and seek for other places that include their QAs more often. If this is something you can live on, then I suggest you don't be to quick to dismiss this job yet.

Comment: Totally using comments incorrectly...but regarding 10 years comment I can see what you mean there. However, most of the QA industry considers 'test early and often' and including QA as pretty much dogma. It's not just newbie me that views this as important. Therefore, if I stay, I run the risk of practicing QA perpendicular to the mainstreams ideology in my field. Which I don't mind if it is effective, however I don't see any benefit of shutting us out of high level discussions, in fact I see it as problematic. But maybe I'm not making a good enough case?